# Rutherford's alpha particle scattering experiment for sheets made of different metals

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms, atomic-structure

The correct order of increasing number of alpha particles passing undeflected through the foils of Au, Ag, Cu and Al of 1000 atoms thickness each in an alpha scattering experiment of Rutherford would be?

Comment: Are you talking about the Rutherford's gold foil experiment? I read that the gold foil was 400 atoms thick. Why did you title this "size of atom question?"   Size of which atom?

Comment: @suse The thickness of the foil is same in all four options here, so I think that's irrelevant. I think we have to look at the number of protons in the nucleus here, or maybe the size of the nucleus.